# How to parse a list of lists in PHP,

Tags: php

I have this PHP+ HTML application that for each item in the item-list:

```
<input type="text" style="visibility: hidden" name="dataKey[]"  value=' . $single_product_info->unique_data_key . ' >
 //some extra data here 
 <select class="SELECTCATEGORY" name="select_category_for_newProduct[]" multiple="multiple">';
```

so, when a button submit clicked, I will get a list of list from "SELECTCATEGORY",

in php function, I have as following

```
$datakey = $_POST['dataKey']; 
$category_id_pershop = $_POST['select_category_for_newProduct'];
```

I am trying to parse the list of data I received in the way that

```
foreach($datakey as $key => $value){
   $data_key => $value,
   $categoriys_per_item = $category_id_pershop[$key];
   //here I try to access the list 
}
```

the difficulty I have now is I can not parse the lists from the one list that I get from HTML input,

I am trying to solve the problem that I have a list of products, for each of them, has some attributes such as key, price and a list of categories,

when user click the submit button from HTML interface, I need PHP function to parse the data, I am not sure if my php idea could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "bind" your datakey to your categories.

```
<select class="SELECTCATEGORY" name="select_category_for_newProduct[' . $single_product_info->unique_data_key . '][]" multiple="multiple">';
```

That way, when you iterate over the array you already have the datakey for the categories and other data you want to submit. Like below:

```
$category_id_pershop = $_POST['select_category_for_newProduct'];

foreach($category_id_pershop as $datakey => $categories){
    foreach ($categories as $categoryId) {
        // logic with the individual category
    }
}
```

I hope I could answered your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot, it helps!!! however I lost the access to another variable such as "$platform = $_POST['platform'];
    $shop = $_POST['shop_name']; ", and more,  I used to access them in the for-loop in my initial question, in a way like "$shopinfo = $shop[$key];, $platform_info= $platform[$key], and for $data_key itself I use the $value ", But now with the new for-loop you provided, I tried this " $shopinfo = $shop[$datakey]; "  and get empty value back, could me help me further? I appreciate

Comment: Or, is that possible to "bind" more than one variable to "category"?